# Blender Rendering of Collada is much worse than Meshtool Rendering

Tags: 3d, rendering, blender, collada, sketchup

I'm new to 3D rendering, so I apologize in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a Collada (.dae) file of a [model](http://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/b5402cf0-fde5-400c-ba37-4457022a1087/American-Antique-Silverware-Cabinet) from 3D Warehouse.

My goal is to render it in Blender to appear similar to the way it does in the preview image on 3D Warehouse.

When I use a tool called [Meshtool](http://github.com/pycollada/meshtool), the model renders as expected.

[image: Meshtool rendering (desired)]

When I try to import the file into Blender and render it, many of the surfaces look distorted and patchy.

[image: Blender rendering with bad surfaces]

How can I render this in Blender so that it looks similar to the meshtool rendering, without the black triangles and patches on the surfaces?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe your question will be better in [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks like a case of z-fighting to me. See if [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/935) helps.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on blender.stackexchange.com